# Similarity of matrices over $\Bbb{Z}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a $2 \times 2$ matrix over $\Bbb{Z}$ with characteristic polynomial $x^2 + 1$. Determine whether $A$ is similar to 
$$\pmatrix{0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0}$$
over $\Bbb{Z}$.

I'm so used to working with matrices over fields $\Bbb{Q}$ and $\Bbb{C}$ that I'm not sure how it differs when we switch to non-fields like $\Bbb{Z}$. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that any such $A$ is an element of order $4$ in $SL_2({\bf Z})$. But $SL_2({\bf Z})\cong {\bf Z}_4*_{{\bf Z}_2}{\bf Z}_6$.

In an amalgamated product, the only elements of finite order are those which are conjugate to the elements of amalgamated groups, so every such $A$ is conjugate to the $1\in {\bf Z}_4$ or $3\in{\bf Z}_4$ in $SL_2({\bf Z})$.

$1$ corresponds to the matrix you provided (with the usual identification of $SL_2({\bf Z})$ with the amalgamated product), while $3$ is its inverse. They are not conjugate in $SL_2({\bf Z})$, but they are in $GL_2({\bf Z})$ by $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$. Since any $A$ is conjugate to one of them, all the $A$ are similar.

Comment: Dear tomasz: Are you sure that $A$ is conjugate in $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb Z)$ to $-A$?

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard: Right, right, my mistake, I forgot that ${\bf Z}_4$ has two generators. ;) Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

*Update: the proof below shows a necessary but not sufficient similarity over $\Bbb{Z}$. I will leave here for pedantic reasons. In the following paragraph, I will summarize; please consult references linked.*

*Similarity over $\Bbb{Z}$ implies similarity over $\Bbb{Q}$ but the converse [is not true in general](http://www.people.vcu.edu/~rbreams/research/intmatrx.pdf). The particular case  for $2\times 2$  integral matrices having a characteristic polynomial $f(x) = x^2+1$ is covered by Example $1$ pp. $11$ in [these (PDF) notes: Lectures on Integer Matrices Thomas J. Laﬀey](http://hermite.cii.fc.ul.pt/elc/meetings/im_1997/lectures.pdf). The proof follows from a theorem of Latimer and MacDuffee relating similarity classes to the number of ideal classes of $\Bbb{Z}[\theta]$ where $\theta$ is a complex root of the characteristic polynomial. And in the case of $x^2+1$, $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ is a PID and has class number 1 (see the PDF). Also relevant is  this post in MathOverflow: [Ideal classes and integral similarity](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72213/ideal-classes-and-integral-similarity).*

---

Two matrices $A, B$ are similar over $\Bbb{Z}$ if $x I - A$ and $x I - B$ have the same [Smith normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) over $\Bbb{Q}[x]$.

Recall that the $i$th invariant factor is the ratio between the gcd of all $i\times i$ minors, to the gcd of all $i-1 \times i-1$ minors. So, the SNF of $xI - B = \pmatrix{x & 1 \\ -1 & x}$ is $\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & x^2+1}.$

It's not hard to show that if $A$ has a characteristic polynomial $\lambda^2+1$ then $xA - I$ has a characteristic polynomial $\lambda^2 + (-2x) \lambda + (x^2 + 1).$ Hence, the determinant of $xA - I$ is $x^2 + 1$, which is also the $2$nd determinantal divisor. But $x^2 + 1$ does not factor over $\Bbb{Q}$, and that pretty much forces the $2$nd invariant factor of $xA - I$ to be $x^2 + 1$, and the first invariant factor to be $1$ (since $1$ is the only element in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$ which divides $x^2 +1 $). So the SNF of $xA-I$ is also $\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & x^2+1}.$ Hence $A$ and $B$ are similar over $\Bbb{Z}$.

More in the book [*Integral Matrices* by M. Newman](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0125178506) (chapter III section 14).

Comment: The Smith normal form is usually defined for principal ideal domains

Comment: @Cocopuffs SNF is well-defined for matrices over $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ (see the book by Newman) and in general PIRs (in a paper by Kaplansky. Elementary divisors and modules).

Comment: @JenniferDylan: ${\bf Z}[x]$ is PIR? What about $(2,x)$?

Comment: @JenniferDylan In your reference it looks like you use the Smith normal form over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and claim that the equality is a necessary (but not necessarily sufficient) condition for similarity over $\mathbb{Z}$. But I could be wrong.

Comment: Oops. Sorry. Cocopuffs you're right. I will edit my question. The same argument carries since $x^2+1$ does not factor over $\Bbb{Q}$. (in my comments above I was thinking all the time about SNF being well-defined over $\mathsf{F}[x]$. Sorry for the mix up with Z[x].)

Comment: @JenniferDylan The implication is still backwards

Comment: @Cocopuffs That's true (not sufficient). I have to read more.

Comment: Dear Jennifer: $+1$ for your honesty, and thanks for all your editing work!

Comment: Yes, thanks Jennifer for the background and the editing work!

Answer (score 3):

The following argument is inspired by tomasz's answer. Set 
$$
B:=\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix},\quad G:=\text{SL}(2,\mathbb Z),\quad H:=G/\{\pm\ I\},
$$
($I$ being the identity matrix), and let $\pi:G\to H$ be the canonical projection.

Since $B$ and $-B$ are conjugate in ${GL}(2,\mathbb Z)$, it suffices to verify that $\pi(A)$ and $\pi(B)$ are conjugate in $H$.

The action of $G$ on the upper half-plane $U$ of $\mathbb C$ by Möbius transformations induces a faithful action of $H$ on $U$. It is not hard to check that an element of finite order of $H$ has a fixed point on $U$. Then, using Theorem VII.1 of Serre's **A Course in Arithmetic**, one sees that the order two elements of $H$ are conjugate, as required.

**EDIT.** The following is implicit above and in tomasz's answer:

Two elements of $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb Z)$ having the same finite order are conjugate in $\text{GL}(2,\mathbb Z)$.

Let me also point out that the proof of Theorem VII.1 in Serre's **A Course in Arithmetic** is short, self-contained, and (is it necessary to add?) wonderfully written.

Comment: I thought my answer was out there, involving $SL_2$, but yours goes to $PSL_2$. :-) Still, it is nice to see different ways to look at the same problem. Even if neither yours nor mine looks like it would easily generalize to arbitrary matrices...